# Get Posts via Taxonomy Term Name with Space

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, get-posts

I am trying to retrieve all the post associated with my custom taxonomy term. My custom taxonomy is "Stores". I am using the following code.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
                  'post_type' => 'coupon',
                  'numberposts' => -1,
                  'post_status' => array('publish', 'unreliable', 'draft'),
                  'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'stores',
                      'field' => 'name',
                      'terms' => 'New Store', 
                      'include_children' => false
                    )
                  )
                ));
```

My taxonomy term name is "New Store". Just because it has a space in the title I couldn't get any posts associated with it. I tried the same code on a taxonomy term without a space in the title and it worked.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, i just extracted the taxonomy term id from name and then extarcted the custom posts from it. Here is the code if anyone is looking:

```
$term = get_term_by('name', 'New Store', 'stores');

            $posts = get_posts(array(
              'post_type' => 'coupon',
              'numberposts' => -1,
              'post_status' => array('publish', 'unreliable'),
              'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'stores',
                  'field' => 'id',
                  'terms' => $term->term_id, 
                  'include_children' => false
                )
              )
            ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the posts by slug instead of name. Like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'coupon',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'unreliable', 'draft'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'stores',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'new-store' ),
            'include_children' => false
        )
    )
));
```

Or you could get the posts by term id. like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'coupon',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'unreliable', 'draft'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'stores',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array( 4 ),
            'include_children' => false
        )
    )
));
```

Here you can find a guide on how to know the term id:
https://facetwp.com/how-to-find-a-wordpress-terms-id/

Comment: Thanks for your help but i am specifically looking to get the posts via term name.